Quantum Notation package interferes with integration
In a fresh kernel
Needs["Quantum`Notation`"];
$Assumptions = {Element[{t, t1, t2, t3, 
     t4, \[Delta], \[CapitalOmega], h}, PositiveReals], 
   Element[{j, k, l}, PositiveIntegers]};

Integrate[-a E^(-I j t1 \[Delta]) Sy \[CapitalOmega], {t1, 
   0, (2 \[Pi])/\[Delta]}, GenerateConditions -> False] // Simplify

This should just return 0, why does it change the pi to numerical and block it from simplifying? Does anyone else get this problem? And does anyone actually use this package? The website is down and the author is not reachable

It is not Needs["QuantumNotation"] that creates the problem, but your assumptions. Consider the integral without the assumptions:
Quit[]
Integrate[-a E^(-I j t1 \[Delta]) Sy \[CapitalOmega], {t1, 
   0, (2 \[Pi])/\[Delta]}, GenerateConditions -> False] // Simplify


Note the term (I - I E^(-2 I j \[Pi])) that evaluates to zero for j an integer:
Simplify[(I - I E^(-2 I j \[Pi])), Element[j, PositiveIntegers]]

0


What's up with global assumptions? is there any way I can keep them?

As long as j not an integer. Otherwise you always get zero.
